# Why am i getting incompatible types error?

Tags: java, recursion, jcreator

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   double f = methodC(1234); **//error is on this line & pointing the opening bracket**
   System.out.println(f);

}

    public static void methodC(double a){
        if (a==0){
           System.out.println(0);
    }
            else{
                double n= a/10;
                double r= a%10;
                System.out.println(r);

            }

    }
```

I keep getting these errors whenever I'm doing a program. Don't need the answer to the code.. just want to know why I'm getting these errors.

Answer (score 3):

`methodC` has no return value. It should return a double value for the assignment - `double f = methodC(1234)` to work.

Answer (score 0):

Because `methodC` return `void` and your assignment is expecting a double return value

Change you method signature to

```
public static double methodC (double a) {
    .
    .
    .
    //make it return a double value as a double value is expected by the 
    //variable on the left hand side of the assignment.
    return doubleValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because `methodC` doesn't return anything, yet you're trying to assign its return value to `f`.